# pgsql log: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: java, postgresql

Recently, I found that clients always are waiting until timeout,when they connect to db server.
Some log in here.

We have a database server in postgresql. and in remote, meanwhile about twenty clients connect to this db  server , adding, updating or deleting data.

2013-03-13 23:19:41 HKT 日志:  不完整的启动包
2013-03-13 23:31:11 HKT 日志:  无法从客户端获得数据: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

2013-03-13 23:31:11 HKT 日志:  在客户端联接上的意外 EOF
2013-03-13 23:37:05 HKT 日志:  无法从客户端获得数据: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Usual cause is a software firewall or a bodgy router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify **pg_hba.conf** inside postgres sql installation directory. IPv4 local connections or IPv6 local connections whatever you use.

- For example, original configuratio of IPv4 connection is

  `host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5` which means only local client.
- Change IPv4 local connections to

  `host     all     all     0.0.0.0/0   md5` means allow access from all clients.

[For more information](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/client-authentication.html)

Comment: Thanks for your relpy. those IPs had been added into the pg_hba.conf original.